# jQuery plugin for positioning a watermark in a photo

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, draggable, watermark

Some time ago I'm searching a jQuery plugin that can help me move a watermark on a photo. See an example in the image below:

[image: Seal Move]

Do you know something? I need that returns the X and Y coordinates relative to photo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one [here](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/jq/) with jquery

The drag-ability can be achieved in this plugin [here](http://fmaz.developpez.com/proj/imgwatermark/download.html)

Comment: hope the second link gives you the pathway

Comment: @Swarne27 I seen second link you provided, but i don't know how to save final image ? Kindly help me for the same.